# Is CHKDSK stalling?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, freeze, boot, chkdsk

I have a Lenovo Y510p running on Win8.1. I've tried running a CHKDSK on boot but power issues with the charger meant it died while it was running(11%).

I tried <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to try restarting into safe mode so I could cancel it but it still tried to run CHKDSK. The worse part is it's stuck at 11% again but the animated circling dots above the "Scanning and Repairing..." text isnt appearing. I know I should let it finish but I'm afraid is just froze.

Is it still active? The y510p has no hdd indicator light so I have no idea, shouldn't those animated dots be appearing though? iI it did stall, is there another way to cancel it? To prevent CHKDSK from running on startup from here? Safe mode doesnt seem to work.

Comment: If its stalled there is no way to cancel it. Even if it wasn't stalled once started there is no way to cancel it.  "To prevent CHKDSK from running on startup from here?" there are several dozen questions on the exact instructions to do this on this website.

Comment: I'm asking if it is stalled when the animated dots arent appearing. If it really isnt doing anything then I may as well restart it. If it might still be running despite the absence of the animated dots then I'll just wait and see if it will finish. I need it for work so I sort if need it asap.